# Ruby saving "Model.all" into application-wide variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, variables

I have a model called `Business`, and I want to save `Business.all` into a variable I can access from another part of my Rails application. What is the best way to do this? I am fairly new to Ruby/Ruby on Rails and I know of class and instance variables but I am a bit cloudy on this.

Thanks!

Comment: How much database traffic will `Business.all` generate each time you run it? Is the model so static you could just put all the data in the `Business` class directly? Or is it too huge and dynamic to re-load from the database every time you need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this to be accessible throughout the entire application, you could put it into the application controller found in `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`.

Example:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :find_all_businesses

  def find_all_businesses
    @businesses = Business.all 
  end
end
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at Rails caching. There is a good screencast here:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/115-caching-in-rails-2-1

It also applies to rails 3. This will allow you to expire the cache if a business is added for example.